# Disable mysql foreign key check for specific tables

Tags: mysql, constraints

Is it possible to disable the Mysql foreign key check for specific tables?

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is not built-in functionality for that in MySQL.

You are able to disable FKs - as you may know - but not for a specific tables - but all. 
Below is an example how it works only for a session (from MySQL 5.xx you can do it globally).

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; #Off
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; #On
```

But you could handle this in a different way - with stored procedures.

In theory you could build stored procedure that drop foreign keys from particular tables, save all this (ie table, FK name, references) to a table so you could retrieve all that later and based on that re-create the same FKs you had before.

But the question here is also about timing - for how long you would like to make them disabled- and primary what is reason behind (some big data inserts, updates, deletions etc).